# plotly resized after plotlyProxyInvoke addTraces

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I'm writing a `shiny` app where some data points in a `plotly` boxplot are highlighted based on the *ids* of points selected by clicking on a `leaflet` map.

Highlighting has been done by `plotlyProxyInvoke` and method `addTraces`, as I couldn't get around the `relayout` method.
The problem with this method is that boxplots with many discrete classes, after the new points are added by `plotlyProxyInvoke`, have the x-axis resized.

I hope that the following minimum reproducible example would help to understand my point.
In the example, the `observe` with `plotlyProxyInvoke` is triggered by an action button.

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1234)
my_data <- data.table(class = rep(LETTERS[1:20], 10),
                      val = rnorm(200, 0, 1),
                      type = sample(c(0:10), 200, replace = TRUE))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 3,
      actionButton("button", "Find type = 1")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("boxplot")
    )
  )
)

# Plotly Boxplot
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$boxplot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(source = "boxplot") %>%
      add_trace(
        data = my_data,
        x = ~class,
        y = ~val,
        color = ~I("gray"),
        marker = list(
          color = "black"
        ),
        line = list(color = "black"),
        type = "box",
        boxpoints = "all",
        pointpos = 0,
        jitter = 0.5
      ) %>%
      layout(
        xaxis = list(
          fixedrange = TRUE
        ),
        yaxis = list(
          fixedrange = TRUE
        )
      )
  })

  # Highlight points for type = 1 ----------------------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    
    plotlyProxy("boxplot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke(
        method = "addTraces",
        list(
          x = my_data[type == 1, class],
          y = my_data[type == 1, val],
          type = "scatter",
          mode = "markers",
          hoverinfo = "skip",
          marker = list(
            opacity = 1,
            color = "red",
            size = 10
          )
        )
      )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Of course, the desired behaviour would be to avoid the resizing and highlight the actual points, instead of adding some new ones.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to programmatically select points using [Plotly.restyle](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle), which avoids adding a new trace.

Please see the comments in the code for further information:

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1234)
my_data <- data.table(
  class = rep(LETTERS[1:20], 10),
  val = rnorm(200, 0, 1),
  type = sample(c(0:10), 200, replace = TRUE)
)
setorder(my_data, type) # order matters: so that the selection corresponds to the internal pointNumber (see e.g. click events)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(width = 3,
               actionButton("button", "Find type = 1")),
  mainPanel(plotlyOutput("boxplot"))
))

# Plotly Boxplot
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$boxplot <- renderPlotly({
    # set color for selected points
    # run schema()
    # and navigate: object -> traces -> box -> attributes -> selected -> marker
    # for more info
    plot_ly(source = "boxplot", selected = list(marker = list(color = "red"))) %>%
      add_trace(
        data = my_data,
        x = ~ class,
        y = ~ val,
        color = ~ I("gray"),
        marker = list(color = "black"),
        line = list(color = "black"),
        type = "box",
        boxpoints = "all",
        pointpos = 0,
        jitter = 0.5
      ) %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE),
             yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE))
  })
  
  boxProxy <- plotlyProxy("boxplot", session)
  
  
  # Highlight points for type == 1 ------------------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    # traceNumber = 0
    plotlyProxyInvoke(boxProxy, "restyle", list(selectedpoints = list(which(
      my_data$type == 1
    ))), 0)
  })
  
  # doubleclick events ------------------------------------------------------
  # run schema()
  # and navigate: object -> traces -> bar -> attributes -> selectedpoints -> description
  observeEvent(event_data(event = "plotly_doubleclick", source = "boxplot"),
               {
                 # deselecting all points for all traces
                 plotlyProxyInvoke(
                   boxProxy,
                   "restyle",
                   list(
                     selectedpoints = NULL,
                     selected = list(marker = list(color = "black")),
                     unselected = list(marker = list(opacity = 0.4))
                   )
                 ) 
               })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: result]

---

**Edit**: Another approach based on a second trace instead of `selectedpoints`:

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1234)
my_data <- data.table(class = rep(LETTERS[1:20], 10),
                      val = rnorm(200, 0, 1),
                      type = sample(c(0:10), 200, replace = TRUE))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 3,
      actionButton("button", "Find type = 1")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("boxplot")
    )
  )
)

# Plotly Boxplot
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$boxplot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(source = "boxplot") %>%
      add_trace(
        data = my_data,
        x = ~class,
        y = ~val,
        color = ~I("gray"),
        marker = list(
          color = "black"
        ),
        line = list(color = "black"),
        type = "box",
        boxpoints = "all",
        pointpos = 0,
        jitter = 0.5
      ) %>% add_trace(
        data = my_data[type == 1],
        x = ~class,
        y = ~val,
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "markers",
        hoverinfo = "skip",
        marker = list(
          opacity = 1,
          color = "black"
        )
      ) %>% 
      layout(
        xaxis = list(
          fixedrange = TRUE
        ),
        yaxis = list(
          fixedrange = TRUE
        )
      )
  })
  
  boxProxy <- plotlyProxy("boxplot", session)
  
  # Highlight points for type == 1 ------------------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    plotlyProxyInvoke(boxProxy, "restyle", list(marker = list(
      opacity = 1,
      color = "red"
    )), 1)
  })
  
  # doubleclick events ------------------------------------------------------
  # run schema()
  # and navigate: object -> traces -> bar -> attributes -> selectedpoints -> description
  observeEvent(event_data(event = "plotly_doubleclick", source = "boxplot"),
               {
                 plotlyProxyInvoke(boxProxy, "restyle", list(marker = list(
                   opacity = 1,
                   color = "black"
                 )), 1)
               })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal.Is it possible to prevent changing the default format of data points selected by the `plotly` tools for lasso and rectangular selection? Also, the ideal answer wouldn't require work on the dataset, which, in the real app, is unfortunately filtered dynamically on user inputs and has about 300k rows.

Comment: @Ndr updating a 300k rows `data.table` by reference doesn't sound very painful to me. Nevertheless, we can avoid adding the index column and reset the selected/unselected marker color after a double-click. Please see my edit.

Comment: currently the real App has other reactive actions linked to `plotly_selected`. Is it possible to assign the `restyle` method to a custom subset like `list(mypoints = list(which(my_data$type == 1))), 0)` ?

Comment: [Plotly.restyle](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle) is alway applied to one or more traces - which brings you back to your initial code if you want to apply changes for only a subset of the data.

Comment: @Ndr I added another approach using a second trace. By the way it would have saved me a lot of time if you had mentioned all those restrictions right away - your initial question was just about the axis re-sizing.

Comment: thanks for your time and help. Sorry, but I'm really new to `plotly` and `plotlyProxyInvoke` and I didn't even figure out that these additional elements were actually restrictions.

Comment: @Ndr ok, so you started working on a existing codebase. That makes it difficult. Cheers