# brush in shiny is resetting despite resetOnNew=FALSE. What can I do about it?

Tags: r, shiny, brush

I want to keep the brush on a shiny plot even if the data changes. Have a look at the following example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("po1", brush = brushOpts(
    "br",
    direction = "x"
  )),
  textInput("ti", "Title")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$po1 <- renderPlot({
    if (input$ti!=""){
      return(ggplot(iris)+geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Petal.Length))+ggtitle(input$ti))
    } else {
      return(ggplot(iris)+geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Petal.Width)))
    }
    
  })
  observeEvent(input$br,{
    print(input$br$xmin)
    print(input$br$xmax)
    print("")
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The brush stays active as long as I only change the title of the plot, but when I change the displayed data it disappears. I do not want this behaviour. What can I do in order to keep the brush visible even when the underlying data changes?

---

Setting a title resets the selection:
[image: result]

Comment: (Unrelated, but this might be the 500,000th (existing) question on stack overflow.)

Comment: Great, so where are they and what can I do about my problem?

Comment: I'm afraid that resetOnNew=FALSE only works if you don't modify underlying data and x-y variables, otherwise a reset must occur as brush selection doesn't apply to the same dataset / variables.

Comment: What I do not understand is, why even a change in alpha resets the brush: `pd <- tidyr::pivot_longer(iris[,1:4], !Sepal.Width)` and then depending on the situation `ggplot(pd)+geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=value, alpha=(name=="Petal.Width")+0))+ggtitle(input$ti)` or `name=="Petal.Length"` does not really change the underlying data, only the underlying alpha. Same with size. But what is the usecase of resetOnNew then?

Comment: Please see `?brushOpts`. `resetOnNew` seems to refer to `renderImage` only and not to `renderPlot`. Accordingly, every time your plot gets rerendered the brush is reset (also when changing the title) and we [can't set it back programmatically](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1456) afterwards. Are you bound to using {ggplot2}? We can realize [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70831194/9841389) using {plotly} instead.

Comment: Actually, changing the title does not reset, at least not on my machine. You can copy paste the code from my question if you want to try it out. Thanks for the other links, I will have a look at them.

Comment: I did that and it does reset the selection (using shiny v1.7.5.1). I just added a gif to your question, which is showing the behaviour.

Comment: Oh, I was not clear, should should try out the following: Write "test", then brush, then write "test2". The brush is still there.

Comment: Have you considered [filing an issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues)?